# PHP error connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

ASP/MS SQL guy here trying to write for PHP/MySQL. I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database like this:

```
$cn1=mysqli_connect(gethostname(),"username","password","databasename");
```

But I get error:

```
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'username'@'r6-dallas.domain.com' (using password: YES)
```

My password actually has a $ in it. I escape that like this:

Password: 123$456
Escape: 123\$456

I assume that is correct? Beyond that, I am getting the hostname dynamically (see above), and I copied the username and database name out of my control panel. What might I try next to try to get this resolved?

Thank you!

Comment: Access denied = the username@host/password are incorrect. If you're trying to connect to mysql on the SAME server, then try `user@localhost` instead.

Comment: Find out where the database server is located. If on the same machine as the site, usually it will be 'localhost' (or maybe '127.0.0.1'). If on a different machine, you normally have to give the name or IP address of that machine. In either case, I don't think 'gethostname()' is going to work for you.

Comment: Also check if your mysql user is able to access the server from any host (%) or only localhost (in your server/user management or directly via sql). Perhaps you need to create a duplicate user with same credentials but other host allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the escape sequence, just type the actual password between single quotes.

Comment: If you have a literal $ in the password string, just use single quotes ' to wrap it, and PHP will not attempt to expand the variable name. If you want to use double quotation marks ", you will need `\$`.

Answer (score 1):

Single quote strings are not processed and are taken "as-is"

```
$cn1=mysqli_connect(gethostname(),'username','pa$$word','databasename');
```

Comment: I assume you meant to use single quotes in your answer and not double quotes.

Comment: You're right, I just copied it from the question. Editing it right now.